# How can I print each item in an unknown length list that is a class attribute as a string in python?

Tags: python, class-attributes

I have a class (Student) with  different attributes, such as studentId, address, and courses. My str method for the class returns all the information that the user put in. However, for the attributes that are lists, such as courses, the location of the information is printed out instead of the actual information. Here is the code (sorry it's a little long, there's a bunch of classes):

```
class Person:

    __name = None
    __age = None
    __address = None

    def __init__(self, name, age=0, address=None):
        self.set_name(name)
        self.set_age(age)
        self.set_address(address)
  
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Name: ' + self.__name + '\n' + \
               'Age: ' + str(self.__age) + '\n' + \
               'Address: ' + str(self.__address)

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name    

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def set_age(self, age):
        self.__age = age

    def get_age(self):
        return self.__age

    def set_address(self, address):
        self.__address = address

    def get_address(self):
        return self.__address

class Student(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, studentID= None, age= 0, address= None):
        super(Student, self).__init__(name, age, address)
        self.set_studentID(studentID)
        self.__courses =[]
    
    def __str__(self):
    
        result = Person.__str__(self)
        result += '\nStudent ID:' + self.get_studentID()
        for item in self.__courses:
            result += '\n   ' + str(item)
        return result
            
    def set_studentID(self, studentID):
        if isinstance(studentID, str) and len(studentID.strip()) > 0:
            self.__studentID = studentID.strip()
        else:
            self.__studentID = 'NA'

    def get_studentID(self):
        return self.__studentID   

    def add_course(self, course):
        print('in add_course')
        self.__courses.append(course)
 
    def get_courses(self):
        for i in range(len(self.__courses)):
            return self.__courses[i]    

class Course:

    __courseName = None
    __dept = None
    __credits = None

    def __init__(self, courseName, dept= 'GE', credits= None):
        self.set_courseName(courseName)
        self.set_dept(dept)
        self.set_credits(credits)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_courseName() + '/' + self.get_dept() + '/' + str(self.get_credits())

    def set_courseName(self, courseName):
        if isinstance(courseName, str) and len(courseName.strip()) > 0:
            self.__courseName = courseName.strip()
        else:
            print('ERROR: Name must be a non-empty string')
            raise TypeError('Name must be a non-empty string')

    def get_courseName(self):
        return self.__courseName

    def set_dept(self, dept):
        if isinstance(dept, str) and len(dept.strip()) > 0:
            self.__dept = dept.strip()
        else:
            self.__dept = "GE"

    def get_dept(self):
        return self.__dept

    def set_credits(self, credits): 
        if isinstance(credits, int) and credits > 0:
            self.__credits = credits
        else:
            self.__credits = 3

    def get_credits(self):
        return self.__credits

students = []

def recordStudentEntry():   
    
    name = input('What is your name? ')
    age = input('How old are you? ')
    studentID= input('What is your student ID? ')
    address = input('What is your address? ')
    s1 = Student(name, studentID, int(age), address)
    students.append(s1)
    s1.add_course(recordCourseEntry())
    print('\ndisplaying students...')
    displayStudents()
    print()        

        
def recordCourseEntry():
    courses = []
    for i in range(2):
        courseName = input('What is the name of one course you are taking? ')
        dept = input('What department is your course in? ')
        credits = input('How many credits is this course? ')
        c1 = Course(courseName, dept, credits)
        print(c1)
        courses.append(c1)
  
    displayCourses(courses)
    return courses
    
def displayCourses(courses):
    print('\ndisplaying courses of student... ')
    for c in range(len(courses)):
        print(courses[c])
    
def displayStudents():
    for s in range(len(students)):
        print()
        print(students[s])

recordStudentEntry()
```

This is how the code above prints out the 'displaying students...' part:

```
displaying students...

Name: sam
Age: 33
Address: 123 st
Student ID:123abc
   [<__main__.Course object at 0x000002BE36E0F7F0>, <__main__.Course object at 
0x000002BE36E0F040>]
```

I know that it is printing out the location because I need to index into the list. However, the length of the list will be different every time. Normally if I wanted to index into a list, for example, to print a list of names, I would do:

```
listOfNames = ['sam', 'john', 'sara']
for i in range(len(listOfNames)):
    print(listOfNames[i])
```

or

```
listOfNames = ['sam', 'john', 'sara']
for i in listOfNames:
    print(i)
```

(not sure what if any difference there is between the 2 ways since they both print out the same way:)

```
sam
john
sara
```

How can I write something like the indexing into a list technique shown here in my str method for my class so that it prints the information and not the location?

Comment: Just like you did for `Student`, you have to do it for `Course`.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: It seems you already did it (it = write a `__str__` method for the `Course` class, and use it in the `__str__` method of the `Student` class), I'm not sure why you even get the output you showed.

Comment: And you can print each item in a list of unknown length by iterating over the list, which you already did: `for item in self.__courses: result += '\n   ' + str(item)`

Comment: So why is it still printing out like this?

Comment: I don't know. This is too much code for me to want to debug this for you. Please see [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and how to create a [mre]. In particular, it's annoying that I have to type in various things in order to run the program. You should replace the `input(...)` by fixed values for the example.

Comment: As an aside, **stop writing Python like this**. Stop writing getters and setters, stop using double-underscore name mangling, that *is not private*. Why do you create a bunch of pointless class variables assigned to `None` only to shadow then with instance variables in `__init__`. I highly suggest using another tutorial, because the one you are using is not teaching you idiomatic python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good to keep to the standard conventions for Python, such as naming
private attributes for objects with single underscores, not double underscores.
The latter are reserved for Python "internal" attributes and methods.
Also, it is convention to use object attributes for objects with get/set methods,
not class attributes. This will make it easier to inspect your objects, while
still maintaining data hiding. Example:

```
class Course:
    def __init__(self, courseName, dept= 'GE', credits= None):
        self._courseName = None
        self._dept = None
        self._credits = None
        self.set_courseName(courseName)
...
```

Your question about why the courses don't print out the way you expected
is rooted in a programming error with the way you programmed the recording
of courses. In `recordCourseEntry()`, you record two courses and put them
in a list. However, you pass that to your Student object using a method
intended for one course at a time. My suggested fix would be:

```
...
    # s1.add_course(recordCourseEntry())
    courses = recordCourseEntry()
    for course in courses:
        s1.add_course(course)
...
```

This will probably be enough to get you going. An example output I got was:

```
Name: Virtual Scooter
Age: 33
Address: 101 University St.
Student ID:2021
   ff/GE/3
   gg/GE/3
```